# Missing parts or texture when importing sketch-up model in Blender

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, collada

Disclaimer: I am everything but a Blender expert.

When I go to https://www.shapenet.org/taxonomy-viewer to the car category and click on a model and click on Source I end up on 3dwarehouse.sketchup website where I can download a collada file (readable by blender).

For instance https://3dwarehouse.sketchup.com/model.html?id=2d096d5dc0e0eeb370a43c2d978e502e shows a 2006 Honda Civic.

After importing it in Blender (File -> Import -> Collada) I end up with different results depending on the model I clicked on:

Either:

-I cannot see anything except the two extreme points
-I can see the body of the car and wheels in two different places
-I can see the body of the car without the tires
-I can see the whole thing normally

In every case whenever I render it I also get black texture artifacts everywhere.

However in shapenet viewer everything is perfectly normal in every case !

How to import it correctly to blender to render it and obtain approximately the same kind of render shapenet displays ?

Comment: **sounds** like z fighting (caused by faces occupying the same exact space) but can't tell just by a description

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information. Please show an image of what you are seeing in blender, the links you posted do not give any information on the problem.

Comment: 3D Wahrehouse models and sketchup models are well know for very poor quality, inverted normals and don't generally cooperate well with other applications. Also read https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541

Comment: I will update my question with some concrete examples